# Unable to add dynamic textView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to add textview dynamically for which I have added the below code.But I am do not see any textview on my activity. I cant add a listview as I am already using recycleview . Any one any error ?

```
              {

                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    LinearLayout review_layout = (LinearLayout) rootMovieView.findViewById(R.id.review_comment);

                    for (ReviewsResult comment : review.getReviewsResults()) {

                        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_movie_comments, review_layout, false);

                        TextView tvCommentBy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comment_by);

                        TextView tvCommentContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comment_content);

                        tvCommentContent.setText(comment.getContent());
                        tvCommentBy.setText(comment.getAuthor());

                        review_layout.addView(view);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: do you call setContentView correctly in activity

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this

```
View myLay;   // view that contains you textView
LinearLayout rootlay;   //root view in which you want to add

    myLay = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_movie_comments,
                    null);

    TextView tvCommentBy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comment_by);

    TextView tvCommentContent = (TextView) myLay.findViewById(R.id.tv_comment_content);

       tvCommentContent.setText(comment.getContent());
       tvCommentBy.setText(comment.getAuthor());

       rootlay.addView(myLay);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Do below two changes and check weather it is working or not, as nothing else seems to wrong in code.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); 

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_movie_comments, null);
```

Comment: Sorry mate ,It does not add the views.

Answer (score 0):

rootMoviewView is not the rootView it was a recylceView in a rootView .This way the textview is generated in rootView not in recylceView.